# QGIS Server 3.4 layers not valid

Tags: qgis-server

I am using the QGIS Server 3.4 docker image of CampToCamp from docker hub.
I have shapefiles and TIFF files in a /home/gisserver/data/etc/gisserver folder, on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine.
In the /home/gisserver/data/etc/gisserver is the project.qgs file with one shapefile layer.

To serve the layer with WMS, I set the following in the project properties, the minimum is checked, under "WMS Capabilties", the "Advertised extent", "CRS restrictions" are checked.
In the "CRS restrictions" box, is EPSG:4326, and I used the "Use Current Canvas Extent" button to fill in the values for "Advertised extent".

I started the server in the /home/gisserver/data directory with the command specified on the docker page for QGIS server.

When requesting the capabilities http://localhost:8380/?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities I get the following response

```
<ServerException>Layer(s) not valid</ServerException>
```

When removing the layer, and save the project empty, with no layers, I get a proper response.
I have checked the layers CRS and the projects CRS is in sync, it is EPSG:4326.
I also have set the QGIS_SERVER_LOG_LEVEL to 0, but can't get the logfile.

It looks like it should be located in the /var/log/apache2 directory in the docker container, but all the files in there have 0 byte sizes.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

After removing the containers and images for QGIS Server 3.4, and pull it fresh again, I got a "Project Error".
When executing the command

> docker logs conainer_name

I could see an error

`06:32:14 CRITICAL Server[68]: Error when loading project file '/etc/qgisserver/project.qgs': Unable to open /etc/qgisserver/project.qgs` in the log.

When looking at the rights on the file I could see that the "group" and "other" had no rights on the project file

> -rw------- 1 1000 1000  32716 Feb  7 07:02 project.qgs

when adding read rights to "group" and "other" on the file

> -rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  32716 Feb  7 07:02 project.qgs

I get the expected result when requesting the capabilities.